# Number Theory: Unique Factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I'm trying to prove unique factorization for the set of polynomials in *x*, with integer coefficients.

I have tried proving that the analogous Euclidean algorithm works for such polynomials, using “degree” instead of “norm" if that makes sense, but couldn't quite get it. If anyone could help me out that would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: $\mathbb Z[x]$ could be a unique factorization domain even if it's [not a Euclidean domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300106/why-is-mathbbzx-not-a-euclidean-domain-what-goes-wrong-with-the-degree-f)