# Doubt about Artin’s Algebra Theorem 2.3.3 Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

I was able to follow most of the proof but I don’t understand how the author concludes that $r=0$ at the final part. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify. Thanks

Comment: If $\,r  := n\bmod a\neq 0$ then it is a positive elt of $S$ smaller than $a$, contra minimality of $\,a\ \ $

Comment: We can also do the descent using subtraction (vs. mod = remainder), e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) where it is used to derive the Bezout equation for the gcd - corresponding to the (extended) Euclidean algorithm (in subtractive or mod = remainder form).

Comment: The descent can be expressed more constructively as an *algorithm* to find a generator: choose a positive $\,a_1\in S.\,$ If $\,a_1\,$ divides all $\,n\in S\,$ then it generates $S$. Else some $\,n\in S\, $ is not divisible by $\,a_1\,$ so we obtain a smaller elt of $S$ via $\,a_2 := n\bmod a_1.\,$ Repeating, if $\,a_2\,$ doesn't generate then we find a smaller $\,a_3\in S,\, \ldots.\,$ Since $\Bbb N\,$ is well-ordered the sequence $\,a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > \ldots > a_k> 0\,$ must terminate with some $\,a_k\,$ that generates $\,S.\ \ $

Comment: We can also descend using $\,a_{k+1} := \gcd(n,a_k)\  (= i n + j a_k\,$ so is in $S).\,$ Then the algorithm computes a generator by taking  gcds of elts of $S$ till we get the gcd of *all* elts of $S$, which is clearly a generator (prove it!).

Comment: The method in the prior comment can be viewed as a generalization of the Euclidean algorithm from $\Bbb Z$ to any PID - see the [Dedekind Hasse Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1185396/242).  The analogous result for PIDs is that each nonzero ideal is generated by any elt having least number of prime factors (the above descent by gcd yields a *proper* factor of $\,a_k\,$ so it has fewer prime factors).

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ wasn't 0, it would be a positive integer, but the inequality $0\leq r < a$ tells us that it would be a positive integer smaller than $a$. However, since we chose $a$ to be the smallest positive integer in $S$ and $r\in S$, this yields a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $r = n-qa$ is an element of $S$ by the fact that $S$ is a group. If for
a contradiction $r > 0$, then we know that $r$ will satisfy the compound inequality $0 < r < a$. However, this means that $r$ is an element of $S$ that is *smaller* than $a$, a contradiction to how we chose $a$ to begin with. Hence, it must be the case that $r = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The proof states that $n=qa+r$, where $n\in S$ and $a$ is the smallest positive integer in $S$. Then $qa\in S$, since $S$ is a subgroup.

Then $r=n-qa$ lies also in $S$ as $S$ is a subgroup. But $r$ is the remainder of dividing $a$ into $n$ and so by def. $0\leq r <a$
But $a$ is smallest with the properties $a>0$ and $s\in S$. This forces $r$ to be $0$.