# Does validity of Bezout identity in integral domain implies the domain is PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

> Let $D$ be an integral domain such that for any $a,b \in D$, $Da+Db$ is a principal ideal. Then must $D$ necessarily be a principal ideal domain i.e. should all the ideals of $D$ be principal ?

Comment: No, e.g. the ring of all algebraic integers or entire functions.

Comment: @BillDubuque : Thanks , can you please provide an answer proving the set of all algebraic integers satisfies the condition but is not a PID ? (I don't know about Entire functions ) are there any other simpler examples ?

Comment: See the link in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/218516/242)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common examples of non-PID Bezout domains are the rings of all algebraic integer or entire functions, e.g. [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/218516/242) For a simpler example one may consider the semigroup ring $\, F[x^{\Bbb Q_{\ge 0}}].\, $ Below is a sketch of this example from M. S. Osborne's *Basic Homological Algebra*, p. 92.

[image]