# Is it always true that in an integral domain $R$, if $x,y\in R$ and $x,y$ coprime then $ux+vy=1$ for some $u,v\in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is it always true that in an integral domain $R$, if $x,y\in R$ and $x,y$ coprime then $ux+vy=1$ for some $u,v\in R$?

I know the converse is true. I don't know if this direction is true.

If the statement is true. 
Given an integral domain $R$ and let $x,y \in R$. We let $h$ to be the hcf of $x$ and $y$. Then $x=ha$, $y=hb$. $a,b$ are coprime. Hence $ua+vb=1$ and $ux+vy=h$. Then $R$ is a Bezout domain.

It seems like only when $R$ is a Bezout domain, the proposition is true.

Comment: I just did a quick search and found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121691/if-coprime-elements-generate-coprime-ideals-does-it-imply-for-any-a-b-in-r-th

Comment: How do you define "coprime"?  In an arbitrary integral domain, you don't have a gcd.

Comment: It is true in *Bézout domains* (finitely generated ideals are principal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in a Unique Factorization Domain, where (presumably) being coprime means that the only common factors are units, it’s not true. Try the UFD $k[x,y]$, polynomials in two variables over a field. There, $x$ and $y$ are coprime in this sense, but there are no polynomials $g$, $h$ (in the two variables) such that $xg+yh=1$.