# Definition of coprime in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, definition

If $R$ is a unique factorisation domain, what is meant by two elements $x,y\in R$ being coprime? We decompose them as $x=up_1\dots p_n$ and $y=u'q_1\dots q_r$, such taht these $p_i,q_j$ are prime elements. Does $x,y$ being coprime mean that $p_i\ne q_j$ for each $i,j$?

Comment: I would think it means that if $a\in R$ such that $a\mid x$ and $a\mid y$, then $a$ is a unit. But I don't have a book with a definition with me at the moment, so I can't confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One definition for a PID is that $a$ and $b$ are called coprime if $Ra+Rb=R$, i.e., they generate coprime ideals. How this is related is explained here:

[If coprime elements generate coprime ideals, does it imply for any $a,b\in R$ that $\langle a\rangle+\langle b\rangle=\langle \gcd (a,b)\rangle$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121691/if-coprime-elements-generate-coprime-ideals-does-it-imply-for-any-a-b-in-r-th)

Since $R$ is a UFD, it is a [gcd-domain](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/UFD_is_GCD_Domain), so there exists a gcd for all non-zero elements. Then $a$ and $b$ are coprime, iff $gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: When we say $gcd(a,b)=1$ we mean that it is unique up to associates, and $1$ is a representative for this class of associates?

Comment: Yes, indeed. For example, the gcd in $R=K[x]$ the ring of polynomials over a field $K$.

Comment: By your definition, is it true that elements are co-prime if and only if $gcd(a,b) = 1$?  In the UFD $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ the elements $x$ and $y$ have gcd 1 but are not coprime, i.e. $\langle x , y \rangle \neq C[x,y]$?

Comment: You are right, $Ra+Rb=R$ is for PID. For UFD's it may not be true, see your example. Then only no prime element is a common divisor.