# Coprime elements generate coprime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Is this true in any commutative rings? I.e.
$$\gcd(a,b)=1\implies (a)+(b)=R$$
I think there must be some conditions on the ring to make this implication otherwise it does not work.

This may related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121691/if-coprime-elements-generate-coprime-ideals-does-it-imply-for-any-a-b-in-r-th) here.

Comment: This is not true in arbitrary rings. For (counter)example, in a polynomial ring in two variables $R=k[x,y]$, we have $\gcd(x,y)=1$, but $(x)+(y) \neq R$.

Comment: In which domain is it true?

Comment: Gcds do not exist in general. Rings in which they exist are called `gcd domains`, and they are integrally closed domains.  U.F.D.s are gcd domains, but the converse is false.

Comment: The implication you mention is true in P.I.D.s or more generally in Bézout domains for the non-noetherian case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in arbitrary rings. For (counter)example, in a polynomial ring in two variables $R = k[x,y]$, we have $\gcd(x,y)=1$, but $(x)+(y) \neq R$.

It is true in [Bézout domains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain). I don’t know if it’s *equivalent* to being a Bézout domain.

Comment: $K$ is a field?

Comment: $k$ can be a field but it doesn’t have to be. For $R$ to be a domain we must have $k$ a domain. That’s all I need for the $k[x,y]$ example. If you want a simple, concrete example, then take $k=\mathbb{Z}$ or a field.